# Windows Store App Icon doesn't appear on Metro

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

In this occasion the problem I'm facing is related with the icon that appears in the metro menu in Windows 8, when developing an App. At the beginig, I was able to see the icon when developing the App (*pressing F5*). However, now I can't see the App Icons in the Metro menu. But when searching the App using the **Windows icon + Q, I** can see the icon of my app.

I realized out the this star happening when I was changing the default splash screen and icons by a custom ones. I have a red icon for the spalsh screen for scale 100 saying: **A mixture of images with and without "scale" or "targetsize" qualifiers exists in this project for the logical name "Assets...."  When a mixture exists, files without the qualifier are ignored.**

I'm not sure if this is causing that the icon is not appearing.

Does any one have a clue?

Regards!

Comment: Have you updated to Windows 8.1? In Windows 8.1 new installed Application doesn't appear in the start menu automatically. You have to pin them there.

Comment: Hi Ja. Yes, I have upgraded to Windows 8.1. The wired part is that I was able to see the Icon in the Metro menu even when I upgraded to 8.1. I wll try to pin the app manually and a let you know. Thaks for your help

Comment: Hi again Jan. just to let you know that due to the upgrade to windows 8.1 was the problem for my app. I pin it to the metro menu and now it appears as it should be ;-)

Comment: great, I posted my comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 8.1 new installed Application doesn't appear in the start menu automatically. You have to pin them there.

For this got to the metro start menu, swipe down (or click the arrow at the bottom left), search for your app -> select it -> select `pin to start` in the app bar.